# Getting rows in Microsoft Access to refer to other rows

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a Microsoft Access table of data with 3 fields: "part_number", "date_of_price_change" and "new_price", but I need to convert the "new_price" field to show the "price_change", rather than the full "new_price" of each part on each date.

This will obviously involve some process that looks at each unique part number on each date and looks up the price of the record with the same part number with the next earliest date and deduct the prices to get the price change.

Problem is, I have no idea how to do this in Access and there are too many records for Excel.  Can anyone assist with how to do this in Access?  (Note that date changes can happen any time and are not periodic).

Many thanks in advance.

Ana

Comment: Why did you tag mysql in this?

Comment: Also, you should not change the structure from how it is. What you currently have is base data. What you are after can be derived from this in a view/query much more easily than the price at any given time can be deduced from a long list of price changes.

Comment: I think @SandPiper is suggesting you use a subquery to pull previous price into each record and then calculate the difference. Review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord. Does not change the raw data.

Comment: Cross-posted here https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=294215 and here http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=66588 !

Answer (score 0):

Add the new column price_change as a Money data type, then run a query something like below. Make sure you backup the table first with an APPEND table to a new table, just in case. Since it is a new column i may not matter.

```
UPDATE 
   T1 
SET 
   T1.price_change = T1.new_price - Nz((SELECT top 1 T2.new_price from MyTable T2 WHERE T2.part_number = T1.Part_Number ORDER BY date_of_price_change DESC),0) 
FROM 
   MyTable T1
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the code Daniel.

Much appreciate the effort